# How to use a variable for a path with Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

I have set up a variable that defines a location to fonts but stylus/console is not showing me the fonts and not throwing any errors.

```
$as-font-path = '../assets/fonts/';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('{$as-font-path}fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
}
```

When I go to developers tool and the Network tab and locate to the css file it does not show my the content of the variable but: `src: url("{$as-font-path}fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");` . So I am not sure how to proceed.

I am using gulp version 3.9.0.

Any help appreciated.

[Stylus documentation](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/interpolation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately currently Stylus doesn't support interpolation inside strings. You should use concatenation in this case:

```
$as-font-path = '../assets/fonts/';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url($as-font-path + 'fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
}
```

Comment: Ok now I know. Your solution worked perfectly though this time. Thank you for the answer.